# Automatically run application multiple times with files from same folder

Tags: windows-7, command-line, csv

I hope this question is appropriate for this forum.

I have a standalone application - an `.exe` file called `ratingsCalculator.exe`. When I open it manually it first asks me to type the filename of a csv file in the same folder as the application.  It then asks for a value (alpha), and then a second value (beta) - which have to be manually entered. After entering the beta value it gives me the message that an output file has been created.

This screenshot is an example for a file that I have called `tennis.csv` where I set alpha to .3 and beta to .1:

[image]

What I want to do is have many csv files all with different filenames in the folder. I want to run all through this application with the same alpha and beta value. However, I do not want to do this manually as for 1000 csv files it would take too long.

Using Windows 7, I have tried this in the command line after changing the directory to the location of the application and files:

```
find -name "*.csv" -exec ratingCalculator {} \
```

Unfortunately the error message I get is:

```
"FIND: Parameter format not correct"
```

so clearly, I am not managing to add in the parameters correctly and this is what I am wondering how to do.

Comment: You appear to be confusing `cmd` and `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a simple C++ application which generates InputTester.exe:

```
#include <iostream>
void main() {
    int a,b,c;
    std::cout << "Number 1: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Number 2: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "Number 3: ";
    std::cin >> c;
}
```

Then you could create a VBS file in the same location as the above exe which looks like this:

```
dim objShell : set objShell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
for i = 1 to 10
    objShell.Run "InputTester.exe", 9
    wscript.Sleep 500 
    objShell.SendKeys 1
    objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    wscript.Sleep 500
    objShell.SendKeys 2
    objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    wscript.Sleep 500
    objShell.SendKeys i & ".csv"
    wscript.Sleep 500
    objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
next
```

Essentially, it sends keys to the application.  You can adjust the sleeps and values provides in the loop but this could offer one solution.

References:
https://ss64.com/vb/run.html

Comment: this works great thanks - any suggestion on how to close all the windows automatically at the end of the process using vbs?

Comment: After the last enter you could send a ctrl-c with: `objShell.SendKeys "^(c)"`